# How to fill the color in cells A1:A5 and B1:B5 and C1:C5 with the same color using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, range

I am currently using the following code to fill cells in the range A1 to A5, and B1 to B5, with yellow:

```
chartRange1 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A5");
chartRange1.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
Excel.Range chartRange2;
chartRange2 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "B5");
chartRange2.Interior.Color= System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

But it takes 2 `chartRange` objects in order to do this. What if I want to set the same color over a wide range of cells?

Is there a way to do this using a single statement that sets the same color for a larger range of cells?

Answer (score 2):

In your case (A1:A5, B1:B5, C1:C5) you can merge the cells into a contiguous range A1:C5:

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:C5");
```

But a range does not have to be contiguous.  You can also use code like the following:

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:A5,C1:C5,F10:F15");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "B5");
```

Comment: Why do you expect that will have the same effect as the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to just set the `chartRange1` object to `null`, then reinitialize and set the next range?